# Excluir un resultado de una consulta en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql

Estimadxs, buen día, vengo con una duda que me ha surgido y que no se como afrontar. Tenemos esta consulta que se inserta en una tabla temporal:

```
INSERT INTO #tablaPrueba
SELECT dbo.CUESOLIC.Cuota,
        CASE 
            WHEN dbo.FN_telefono_encadena(dbo.Cliente.Id) IS NULL 
                THEN ''
            ELSE dbo.FN_telefono_encadena_celular(dbo.Cliente.Id)
            END AS Telefono,
        'A' AS TipoCuota
FROM dbo.CUESOLIC 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Solicitud 
        ON dbo.CUESOLIC.TITULO = dbo.Solicitud.ANTITSOL 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Cliente 
        ON dbo.Cliente.andnicli = dbo.Solicitud.ANDNICLI 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Documento 
        ON dbo.Cliente.aniddoc = dbo.Documento.aniddoc 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Zona 
        ON dbo.Cliente.acidzona = dbo.Zona.acidzona 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PLANsql 
        ON dbo.CUESOLIC.CODPLAN = dbo.PLANsql.acidplan 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PLANsql AS planOrigen 
        ON dbo.Solicitud.PlanCertificado = planOrigen.acidplan 
    INNER JOIN dbo.FechasSorteo 
        ON MONTH(dbo.CUESOLIC.FechaVencimiento) = dbo.FechasSorteo.mes AND YEAR(dbo.CUESOLIC.FechaVencimiento) = dbo.FechasSorteo.ano
    LEFT JOIN Cliente_Contacto
        ON dbo.Cliente.Id = dbo.Cliente_Contacto.CLI_Id
WHERE (dbo.CUESOLIC.FECGRABAC >= '20200301' 
    OR dbo.CUESOLIC.FECGRABAC IS NULL) 
    AND (dbo.CUESOLIC.FechaVencimiento >= '20200201')
    AND (dbo.CUESOLIC.Titulo = @titulo)
**UNION**
SELECT dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica.Cuota, 
        CASE 
            WHEN dbo.FN_telefono_encadena(dbo.Cliente.Id) IS NULL 
                THEN ''
            ELSE dbo.FN_telefono_encadena_celular(dbo.Cliente.Id)
            END AS Telefono,
        'R' AS TipoCuota
FROM dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica
    INNER JOIN dbo.Solicitud 
        ON dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica.TITULO = dbo.Solicitud.ANTITSOL 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Cliente 
        ON dbo.Cliente.andnicli = dbo.Solicitud.ANDNICLI 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Documento 
        ON dbo.Cliente.aniddoc = dbo.Documento.aniddoc 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Zona 
        ON dbo.Cliente.acidzona = dbo.Zona.acidzona 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PLANsql 
        ON dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica.CODPLAN = dbo.PLANsql.acidplan 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PLANsql AS planOrigen 
        ON dbo.Solicitud.PlanCertificado = planOrigen.acidplan 
    INNER JOIN dbo.FechasSorteo 
        ON MONTH(dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica.FechaVencimiento) = dbo.FechasSorteo.mes AND YEAR(dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica.FechaVencimiento) = dbo.FechasSorteo.ano 
    INNER JOIN PLANsql AS PlanAzul 
        ON Solicitud.ACIDPLAN = PlanAzul.acidplan
    LEFT JOIN Cliente_Contacto --CAMBIAR POR INNER JOIN, ESTÁ CON LEFT POR LOS QUE NO ESTÁN EN CLIENTE_CONTACTO
        ON dbo.Cliente.Id = dbo.Cliente_Contacto.CLI_Id
WHERE (dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica.FECGRABAC >= '20200301' 
    OR dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica.FECGRABAC IS NULL) 
    AND (dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica.FechaVencimiento >= '20200201')
    AND (dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica.Titulo = @titulo)
```

Ahora, luego de haberse insertado todo, lo que hago es hacer un select para que me traiga todas las cuotas:

```
IF @cuota = 0 OR @cuota IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT cuota, TipoCuota FROM #tablaPrueba ORDER BY cuota DESC
    END
```

**La consulta me trae 5 filas:**

```
cuota   TipoCuota
    5   A
    4   A
    3   A
    2   A
    2   R
```

Como se ve, **se repite la cuota 2:**

```
cuota   TipoCuota
    2   A
    2   R
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se vea así?

```
cuota   TipoCuota
    5   A
    4   A
    3   A
    2   R
```

Comment: Y en que criterios te basas para excluir determinada cuota

Comment: Saludos. Me da la impresión que hace falta la regla en que momento o bajo que condición debe mostrar o no **R** o **A**. Una opción que es apliques otro `SELECT` similar al que pones pero usando `EXCEPT` para que "elimines" (en tu caso) a `ID=4`, `Cuota=4` y `Tipo=A` cuando exista `Cuota=4` con `Tipo=R`

Comment: El criterio es que si existe la cuota 4 con el tipo R, se excluya la cuota 4 con el tipo A @Japv

Comment: La condición es que si la cuota 4 tiene dos registros uno de @RobertoLeOr tipo **A** y otro de tipo **R** solo se muestre **R**

Comment: Saludos de nuevo; de forma similar al `UNION` será el que uses `EXCEPT` pero que devuelva la(s) fila(s) que cumplan la condición que mencionas; pero devolviendo la fila donde `Tipo=A` para que la excluya/omita. Con los datos que aportas (creo, no los detecto) no puedo segerirte como quedaria ya que no identifico donde que tabla tiene `Tipo` **A** y **R**

Comment: saludoshe editado la consulta sql para que se entienda un poco mejor @RobertoLeOr

Comment: Saludos. Espero ahora atinarle; de tu **La consulta me trae 6 filas** no se identifica si las columnas (de tu original antes del cambio) son de alias **A** o **B** (o cual de cuales); te ejemplifique con el `UNION` (como referencia) no que así fuera (para que uses `EXCEPT`) aplicando el criterio que das.

Comment: No, te expliico, lo que sucede es que esa es la lógica de la consulta que tengo hecha. Lo que pasa es que es muy grande entonces, la resumí. @RobertoLeOr

Comment: Está bien el esfuerzo de _resumir_ la consulta, pero debes dejar un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) pues con la consulta que publicas actualmente no se explican los resultados que obtienes. Por ejemplo, no hay de dónde salga un registro con tipo 'R' en la unión, ni coincide el número de campos.

Comment: Bueno, ahí dejé toda la consulta para que veas más o menos cómo es. Quité muchísimos campos del select para acotarla lo más posible pero esa es mi consulta y creo que ahora se debería entender mejor lo que necesito @jachguate

Comment: ¿Vas a usar esa tabla temporal después o solo la usas en esa condición?

Comment: La vuelvo a usar luego para filtrar datos @LuisCazares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener solo una fila de cada grupo (en este caso de cada cuota) sin tener que agrupar por todas las columnas, se suele utilizar ROW_NUMBER para enumerar las filas y solo obtener la primera. Sin embargo, como no se puede filtrar directamente, se tiene que poner la consulta en una CTE o una subconsulta.

Dejo un ejemplo con los datos de prueba.

```
DECLARE @cuota int;

SELECT 5 Cuota, 'A' TipoCuota INTO #tablaPrueba UNION ALL
SELECT 4 Cuota, 'A' TipoCuota UNION ALL
SELECT 3 Cuota, 'A' TipoCuota UNION ALL
SELECT 2 Cuota, 'A' TipoCuota UNION ALL
SELECT 2 Cuota, 'R';

IF @cuota = 0 OR @cuota IS NULL
    BEGIN
        WITH cteTablaPrueba AS(
            SELECT  cuota, 
                    TipoCuota,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Cuota ORDER BY TipoCuota DESC) AS rn
            FROM #tablaPrueba 
        )
        SELECT cuota,
                TipoCuota
        FROM cteTablaPrueba
        WHERE rn = 1
        ORDER BY cuota DESC
    END

GO
DROP TABLE #tablaPrueba;
```

Otro detalle que tienes que solucionar, es dejar de usar nombres de 3 partes para las columnas de la consulta. Eso es algo que dejará de funcionar en versiones posteriores de SQL Server. Para evitar eso, es bueno usar alias en todas las tablas. Dejo un ejemplo de como escribiría tu consulta

```
INSERT INTO #tablaPrueba
SELECT CS.Cuota,
        CASE 
            WHEN dbo.FN_telefono_encadena(C.Id) IS NULL 
                THEN ''
            ELSE dbo.FN_telefono_encadena_celular(C.Id)
            END AS Telefono,
        'A' AS TipoCuota
FROM       dbo.CUESOLIC     AS CS
INNER JOIN dbo.Solicitud    AS S  ON CS.TITULO           = S.ANTITSOL 
INNER JOIN dbo.Cliente      AS C  ON S.andnicli          = C.ANDNICLI 
INNER JOIN dbo.Documento    AS D  ON C.aniddoc           = D.aniddoc 
INNER JOIN dbo.Zona         AS Z  ON C.acidzona          = Z.acidzona 
INNER JOIN dbo.PLANsql      AS P  ON CS.CODPLAN          = P.acidplan 
INNER JOIN dbo.PLANsql      AS O  ON S.PlanCertificado   = O.acidplan 
INNER JOIN dbo.FechasSorteo AS FS ON CS.FechaVencimiento >= DATEFROMPARTS(FS.ano, FS.mes, 1) 
                                 AND CS.FechaVencimiento <  DATEADD( MM, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(FS.ano, FS.mes, 1))
LEFT JOIN Cliente_Contacto  AS CC ON C.Id                = CC.CLI_Id
WHERE (CS.FECGRABAC       >= '20200301'  OR CS.FECGRABAC IS NULL)
AND   CS.FechaVencimiento >= '20200201'
AND   CS.Titulo           =  @titulo
UNION ALL
SELECT CEH.Cuota, 
        CASE 
            WHEN dbo.FN_telefono_encadena(C.Id) IS NULL 
                THEN ''
            ELSE dbo.FN_telefono_encadena_celular(C.Id)
            END AS Telefono,
        'R' AS TipoCuota
FROM dbo.CuesolicEndosos_Historica AS CEH
INNER JOIN dbo.Solicitud    AS S  ON CEH.TITULO           = S.ANTITSOL 
INNER JOIN dbo.Cliente      AS C  ON S.ANDNICLI           = C.andnicli
INNER JOIN dbo.Documento    AS D  ON C.aniddoc            = D.aniddoc 
INNER JOIN dbo.Zona         AS Z  ON C.acidzona           = Z.acidzona 
INNER JOIN dbo.PLANsql      AS P  ON CEH.CODPLAN          = P.acidplan 
INNER JOIN dbo.PLANsql      AS O  ON S.PlanCertificado    = O.acidplan 
INNER JOIN dbo.FechasSorteo AS FS ON CEH.FechaVencimiento >= DATEFROMPARTS(FS.ano, FS.mes, 1) 
                                 AND CEH.FechaVencimiento <  DATEADD( MM, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(FS.ano, FS.mes, 1))
INNER JOIN PLANsql          AS PA ON S.ACIDPLAN           = PA.acidplan
LEFT JOIN  Cliente_Contacto AS CC ON C.Id                 = CC.CLI_Id --CAMBIAR POR INNER JOIN, ESTÁ CON LEFT POR LOS QUE NO ESTÁN EN CLIENTE_CONTACTO
WHERE (CEH.FECGRABAC        >= '20200301' OR CEH.FECGRABAC IS NULL) 
AND   CEH.FechaVencimiento  >= '20200201'
AND   CEH.Titulo            = @titulo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograr el cometido que buscas *agrupando* por cuota. Dado que los únicos valores a considerar son `A` y `R` y, de estos, te quieres quedar con `R`, puedes utilizar la función `max()` para lograrlo, por ejemplo:

```
select   cuota
       , max(TipoCuota) TipoCuota 
  from #tablaPrueba 
 group by cuota
 order by cuota desc
```

Lo cual te devolverá:

```
cuota       TipoCuota
----------- ---------
5           A
4           A
3           A
2           R

(4 rows affected)
```

Comment: Claro, pero eso implica que si tengo 30 campos en el `SELECT` voy a tener que inlcuirlos en el `GROUP BY`

Comment: No sabría decir, con el ejemplo que muestras, mi respuesta funciona. Si el ejemplo no está completo conceptualmente, no veo cómo podría responder a tu pregunta. Por eso es importante preparar un [mcve] en la pregunta.